# TYPO3 backend workflow when avoiding the storage of data in intermediate table

Tags: typo3, relational-database, extbase

I have a situation as described in the [*ExtbaseFluid*](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/master/en-us/6-Persistence/1-prepare-the-database.html#configure-relationships-between-objects) book:

I would like to store information in the intermediate table which is not recommended at all.

Here is a cite from the warning box of the above linked book chapter:

> Do not store data in the Intermediate Table that concern the Domain. Though TYPO3 supports this (especially in combination with Inline Relational Record Editing (IRRE) but this is always a sign that further improvements can be made to your Domain Model. Intermediate Tables are and should always be tools for storing relationships and nothing else.
>
>
> Let’s say you want to store a CD with its containing music tracks: `CD -- m:n (Intermediate Table) -- Song`. The track number may be stored in a field of the Intermediate Table. However, the track should be stored as a separate domain object, and the connection be realized as `CD -- 1:n -- Track -- n:1 -- Song`.

So I want not to do what is not recommended. But thinking about the workflow for the editor that results of the recommended solution rises a few question for me.

To stay with this example I would need the following tables:

```
tx_extname_domain_model_cd
tx_extname_domain_model_cd_track_mm
tx_extname_domain_model_track (which holds the track number)
tx_extname_domain_model_track_song_mm
tx_extname_domain_model_song
```

From what I know this would end in the situation that the editor would need to create following records:

- one record for the `cd`
- one record for the `song`
- now the editor can create one record for the `track`.

  There the track number is added.

  Furthermore the `cd` record needs to be assigned as well as the `song`.

**So here are my questions:**

1. I guess this workflow cannot be improved with some (to me unknown) TCA setup?
2. An editor cannot directly reach the `song` when the `cd` record is opened?

   Instead first she / he has to open the `track` record and can from there navigate to the `song`?
3. Is it really that bad to store data in the intermediate table? The TYPO3 table `sys_file_reference` does the same!? But I wonder how those data could be shown (because IRRE is not possible because it shall only be used for `1:n` relations ([source](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/master/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Inline/Index.html#irre-inline)).

Comment: In general intermediate tables aren't supposed to store data at all, therefore that's warning in the book. IMHO the best option would be stay with that and store CD and Track in custom entities and join them with mm table not containing any unnecessary data.

Comment: @biesior That answers only my third question. Can you give me hints for those other two questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question you have to ask yourself is: **Do I want to do coding by the book, or do I want to create a pragmatic approach to solve a customer's problem?**

In this specific case the additional problem is, that the people who originally invented Extbase had a quite sophisticated and academic approach, but when it comes to a pragmatic use and performance, they were blocked by their own rules and stuck with coding by the book.

Especially this example and the warning message shows a way of thinking that was **one of the reasons, why I never actually used Extbase** but went for Core-API methods to create performant and pragmatic queries to get the desired result sets. Now that we've got `Doctrine` under the hood, this works like a charm even with quite exotic DB flavors.

Of course `intermediate tables` are a good idea and of course those `intermediate tables` can and should be enriched with additional data fields, that do **not** require a 3rd, 4th or nth table to store i.e. a simple set of dropdown options, since this can easily be handled with `attributes` configured in `TCA`, as it is shown here: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/master/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Inline/Examples.html

`sys_file_reference` is the most prominent example since it provides exactly that kind of additional information that should not be pumped into additional tables - and guess what, **the TYPO3 core does not make use of a single line of Extbase code to deal with that data** or almost any other data of the core tables.

To answer your last question: Take a look at the good old IRRE Tutorial to get a clue how to do m:n connections with intermediate inline tables.
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/irre_tutorial/0.4.0/Manual/Index.html#intermediate-tables-for-m-n-relations

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the issue, sometimes the intermediate table is an entity, sometimes not. In this example the intermediate table is the track, which would contain: [uid, cd, song, track_no, ... (whatever else needed to define the track)]

Be carefull when you define your data, that you do not make it too advanced.